# c++ visual studio 2015 and OCCI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, occi

Is it possible to use OCCI (Oracle c++ call interface) within Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community and if so, how?

In the Oracle download section I can only find OCCI for Visual Studio 2010 or lower. Do I need to switch to VS2010 to use it?

Comment: If it's compiled static library, you can probably just link it using VS2015... If it's just source, VC2015 will auto upgrade the project.

Answer (score 3):

I recently did an OCCI setup on my own machine recently. I can tell you that the OCCI seems to be **very** picky that you use the right OCCI library with the corresponding VC++ version. So while I have not tried your suggested setup, I am going to guess that no, it will not work. Try using VS2010.

In addition, if you are trying to setup OCCI for the first time, I found [this](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/07/getting-started-with-occi-windows.html) blog post very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can download oracle instant client basic 12c  and oracle instant client sdk 12c which includes VS2013 occi libs and dlls.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

I can link these into my VS2015 projects but there are definitely issues in Debug mode, even linking against oraocci12**d** because of the runtime mismatch. Release mode on the other hand works fairly well. But ideally we need Oracle to release VS2015 (and now VS2017) libraries, or at most use VS2013.